# Validating multiple method arguement in spock

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, assert, spock

I'm mocking the transformer call like below

```
3 * transformer.transform(_ as Traveler, _ as Map<String, String>, _ as List<Train>) >>> [expectedObject[0], expectedObject[1], expectedObject[2]]
```

able to mock successfully.

Now, want to assert the 2nd arguement which is Map<String, String>.

Tried like below

```
3 * transformer.transform(_ as Traveler, _ as Map<String, String>, _ as List<Train>) >> {
            Map<String, String> test->
                assert test['abcd'] == '1234'

                test
}
```

But not able to assert. How to assert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [argument constraints](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints) in your case the [code argument constraint](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_code_constraint) combined with [type constraint](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_type_constraint) is what you want.

I've created a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on the limited code that you provided.

```
interface Transformer {
    String transform(Map<String, String> argument)
}

class ASpec extends Specification {
    def "code argument constraint"() {
        given:
            Transformer transformer = Mock()
        
        when:
            transformer.transform([a: 'hello', b: 'world'])
        
        then:
            1 * transformer.transform({ it.b == 'world'} as Map<String, String>) >> 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJx1ULFuwjAQ3fMVTyxJKoTEippI3ViYqMSAOhjnEizCGdlXqITy78QQ0rTAm9753r13PsNCrlSa8OkU-9K6PTmcI7RYijNcQe6NZKEO77fHcdfMoVz1vSeWNGqiSNfKe3wsD6RBP0JceITClEYrMZY754JKjLQtqB-HtuzbJMMyStJOFlCZI_GsLwOGm8qAZ1hYvUvSXtyT0_a_x2Bu8vvBtZoh3lJd23iMTctP1tVF_PXEUh4sp3h7YXuGkckGWXY3bKA8nlwzRZ4jnocFsLoqrwlNuO2frAt7ooCQ)